# Not able to form SQL Join query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am pretty new to SQL and am trying to write a query to find the logic for something like the following scenario:

```
wk_id | start_date | end_date | status

-----   ----------    ------    ------ 
1       20160101     20160101     SUCCEEDED
2       20160101     20160101     SUCCEEDED
3       20160101     20160101     SUCCEEDED
4       20160101     20160101     SUCCEEDED
5       20160101     20160101     FAILED
6       20160102     20160102     SUCCEEDED
7       20160102     20160102     SUCCEEDED
8       20160102     20160102     FAILED
9       20160102     20160102     FAILED
10      20160101     20160101     FAILED
11      20160101     20160101     FAILED
```

So for 3 days there are a few works submitted, a few have failed and a few have succeeded.

**I want to write a query which returns the total number of works, succeeded works and failed works per each day.**

I am definitely doing this wrong but this is what comes to my mind.

Please point out the errors and explain the logic.

```
select 
       w1.end_date,
       w1.status,COUNT(*) as total_instances, 
       COUNT(*) as as succeeded_instances,
       COUNT(*) as as failed_instances 
from 
       work_instances w1 , 
       work_instances w2
 where 
       w1.status LIKE 'SUCCEEDED' 
       and w2.status NOT LIKE 'SUCCEEDED' 
       and w1.wk_id = w2.wk_id 
 group by 
       w1.end_date,w1.status;
```

Comment: you should use proper INNER JOIN syntax to start with. This comma-separated syntax is archaic and and can cause confusion and/or unexpected results.

Comment: @ADyson it's possible to obtain desired result without `join`, just with one pretty simple select...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak true no doubt, but nonetheless if OP is going use JOINs for anything, they should ensure they do it correctly. That was really my point. Whether a JOIN is necessary for this particular solution is another matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use aggregate function with case when

```
  select 
  w1.end_date,COUNT(*) AS total_work,
  sum(case when w1.status='SUCCEEDED' then 1 else 0 end ) as SUCCEEDED_task, 
  sum(case when w1.status='FAILED' then 1 else 0 end ) as FAILED_task                  
  from 
  work_instances w1 group by w1.end_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more elegant way is using a [FILTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) in an aggregate function call:

```
WITH work_instances(wk_id, start_date, end_date, status) AS (
    VALUES 
        (1, '20160101'::DATE, '20160101'::DATE, 'SUCCEEDED'),
        (2, '20160101', '20160101', 'SUCCEEDED'),
        (3, '20160101', '20160101', 'SUCCEEDED'),
        (4, '20160101', '20160101', 'SUCCEEDED'),
        (5, '20160101', '20160101', 'FAILED'),
        (6, '20160102', '20160102', 'SUCCEEDED'),
        (7, '20160102', '20160102', 'SUCCEEDED'),
        (8, '20160102', '20160102', 'FAILED'),
        (9, '20160102', '20160102', 'FAILED'),
        (10, '20160101', '20160101', 'FAILED'),
        (11, '20160101', '20160101', 'FAILED')      
)
SELECT 
    end_date,
    count(*) AS total_instances,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'SUCCEEDED') AS succeeded_instances,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'FAILED') AS failed_instances        
FROM 
    work_instances
GROUP BY 
    end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT end_date,
       count(*) total_instances,
       count(CASE
               WHEN status = 'SUCCEEDED' THEN
                 1
             END) succeeded_instances,
       count(CASE
               WHEN status = 'FAILED' THEN
                 1
             END) failed_instances
       FROM work_instances
       GROUP BY end_date;
```

The `CASE` will only return a non null value (here it's 1, but it could be anything not null), if the status is the right one. And the `count()` doesn't count nulls only non null values.